# Flex - How project using MVC / MVP pattern

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller, mvp

I would like to know what is best practise for structuring FLEX application using MVC / MVP pattern. I can't find any good example on google.

Comment: Hard to believe you can't find any examples on Google - there are a gzillion tutorials.

Comment: You can implement any pattern you want in Flex yourself, in fact Flex is already a MVC (MVVM) itself. Maybe you should read its documentation more deeply. If you really need them, there are also plenty of frameworks available to decouple and structure your code. We use Parsley (and we love it), but you can also use Cairngorm, Swiz, PureMVC, RobotLegs, Mate, SpringAS. But, as some others will argue, with Flex you actually don't need any of these.

Answer (score 1):

choosing Framework depends on your requirement. 
To know the differences refer [article](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/)

Iam using Robotlegs-Framework which follows MVC pattern,lightweight micro-architecture for Rich Internet Applications.